# Open Outlook Mail Client with To, CC, Subject and Body using Java code

Tags: java, email, outlook

Can someone help me with opening Outlook Mail Client with To, CC, Subject and Body using Java code. Tried with the following code

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

 try {
      desktop.mail( new URI( "mailto:javaexamplecenter@gmail.com?subject=Test%20message" ) );
     } 
catch ( IOException ex )
    {
    }
```

But this code allows me to add only mailto: and Subject , But I need to enter mail address in CC and Want to compose the Body also.
Please someone help me...
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
package org.bnymellon.home;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class sendMail
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException
    {
        String subject="password";
        String body="See%20it";
        String cc="brath@inautix.co.in";

        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().mail( new URI( "mailto:prrout@inautix.co.in?subject="+subject+"&cc="+cc+"&body="+body) );
        } 
        catch ( IOException ex )
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would `URLEncode.encode(param, "UTF-8");" each parameter.

Comment: @Pradeep thanks using your code i am able to open the outlook...but how i will send that email automatically? Please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible Solution using ProcessBuilder is:-

```
    try {
         new ProcessBuilder("Outlook.exe Path on Your System",
            "/m","Pass Parameters for mail like To, CC, BCC, Subject separated by &",
            "/a","mail attachment Path on Your System").start();
        } 
    catch ( Exception ex ) {
    }
```

For example :-

```
    try {
         new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\OUTLOOK.EXE", 
           "/m","test@gmail.com&CC=testCC@gmail.com&subject=testagain&body=testbody",
           "/a","D:\\sample.pdf").start();
        } 
    catch ( Exception ex ) {
    }
```